# How to select random element from an array that is stored in an interface file?

Tags: java, oop

so im writing an assignment for class. I have gotten stuck in my attempts to write a function to select a random element. The array that I am trying to access is stored in an interface file. I have one main file that implements the interface, and then multiple files extending the main file.

I am to write and test out how to select a random element from that interface file. The file contains many different arrays but for testing purposes, I will be selecting the lastName[]. How the function is written below is throwing an out of bounds error, but I don't know how to go about correcting it.

This is the test file:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MemberTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rndNum = rnd.nextInt();

    Member m = new Member();
    Student s = new Student();
    Staff ss = new Staff();
    Faculty f = new Faculty();
    Employee e = new Employee();
    Names n = new Member();


    System.out.println(n.lastName[rndNum]);

    System.out.println(m.toString(true));
  }
}
```

This is the file that implements Names.java

```
public class Member implements Comparable<Member>, Names{

public Member() {}

// randomly fill in all data member.
public void generate() {}

public String toString() {
    return toString(false);
}

public String toString(boolean ok) {
    return String.format("%s%3d-%2d-%4d %15s, %-15s", ok? "Mem " : "", ID / 1000000, ID / 10000
            % 100, ID % 10000, lastName, firstName );
}

//public int compareTo(Member) {}

public int compareTo(Member m) { 
    return ID - m.ID; 
}

public String htmlRow() {
    return String.format("<TR>%s</TR>", htmlColumns());
}

public String htmlColumns() {
    return String.format("<TD>%3d-%2d-%4d</TD> <TD>%15s,</TD> <TD>%-15s</TD>", ID / 1000000, ID / 10000
            % 100, ID % 10000, lastName, firstName );
} 

protected String firstName[], lastName[]; 
protected int ID;
```

}

This is the interface file:

```
public interface Names {

// Fields in interface are always and implicitly public, static and final.
// All methods in interface are implicitly public and abstract.

public static final String lastName [] = {
    "Abdalla", "Andres", "Anzai", "Armstrong", "Arvig", "Ash", "Baca", "Badine",
    "Baehr", "Bair", "Baligad", "Barlow", "Barrett", "Becker", "Bell",
    "Benbow", "Biggs", "Blevins", "Blood", "Bohan", "Bond", "Bonner",
    "Bosch", "Bryson", "Buechele", "Bullis", "Burk", "Burns", "Byron",
    "Calderon", "Careuthers", "Carr", "Carson", "Carter", "Castle", "Chan",
    "Charney", "Christenson", "Cisneros", "Cliton", "Coldewey", "Coodey",
    "Cook", "Cooper", "Coy", "Currie", "Curtis", "Dirkse", "Dirscoll",
    "Dodrill", "Ehlert", "Elias", "Elliott", "Enterline", "Ericsson",
    "Fernandez", "Fisher", "Flory", "Freese", "Fruzza", "Fu", "Fuhrman", "Gage",
    "Garcia", "Garmon", "Giffith", "Gill", "Gillen", "Glascock", "Gomez",
    "Goraya", "Greer", "Hansen", "Hartley", "Hawkins", "Hemme", "Hensley",
    "Hentges", "Herron", "Hightower", "Hines", "Holloway", "Holmes",
    "Issac", "Jackson", "Jagodin", "Jiang", "Johnson", "Jordan", "Jouda", "Joven",
    "Kalpesh", "Katz", "Kaur", "Kegley", "Kimsey", "King", "Kohn", "Kone",
    "LaCasse", "Lackey", "Lathrop", "Le", "Levy", "Lynos", "Maas", "Mackall",
    "Madsen", "Magee", "Maldonado", "McDaneld", "McMillian", "McNeill",
    "Meadors", "Medina", "Metz", "Millikin", "Minner", "Mondragon", "Monge", "Moore",
    "Moreno", "Murkland", "Musick", "Myers", "Neal", "Ngo", "Nolan", "Nunez",
    "O'Neil", "Oropeza", "Owen", "Patel", "Pfister", "Philips", "Picato",
    "Porras", "Porter", "Pratt", "Pryor", "Ragle", "Rai", "Raja", "Rill",
    "Roberts", "Roddy", "Rose", "Roux", "Rubio", "Ruiz", "Saito", "Samidin",
    "Sampson", "Sanchez", "Scanlan", "Schmidt", "Schoberg", "Sheppard",
    "Simmons", "Sison", "Smith", "Snow", "Soto", "Sozinho", "Stevens",
    "Stidham", "Strange", "Sy", "Tamayo", "Taylor", "Thomas", "Tran", "Vincent",
    "Walker", "Wandke", "Ward", "Warner", "Waugh", "Webb", "Wells", "White",
    "Wilson", "Winther", "Wuertz", "Yong" };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Himanshu says, if you dont have the control of the max value of your random, its easy that your code fails with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

try to change the line who gets the integer: `int rndNum = rnd.nextInt();` to `int rndNum = rnd.nextInt(Names.lastName.length);` and should work without problems.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and has allowed me to randomly select a last name now.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem here are these lines in the test code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int rndNum = rnd.nextInt();
...
System.out.println(n.lastName[rndNum]);
```

Now rnd doesn't really take care of what value it is bounded with or what is the maximum range here. You would need to bound it.
So, right now `rnd.nextInt()` can yield 100, 1000, 10000...

This is what you need to control

what you can do is, re-write the following line as:

```
int rndNum = rnd.nextInt();
```

**as**

```
int rndNum = rnd.nextInt()%lastName.length;
```

NOTE: I haven't gone through the whole code, but the first issue I see. Try it out and let know if there are still issues.

Comment: Would you have a fix for getting this line of code System.out.println(m.toString(true)); to use firstName and lastName from that same interface file?